# Windows 8.1: Windows cannot be installed to this disk

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, windows-8.1, installation

I am installing windows 8.1 for the ASUS laptop.

I have two drive in the laptop namely:

```
Drive 1 : 40  GB
Drive 2 : 450 GB
```

At the time of installation I have formated `Drive 1` which I was suppose to use for Operating System installation. After I format I am getting an error:

**Error**:

[image]

**Note**: After googling I came to know that I need to format whole disk and need to convert the type of disk to GPT. But I have an important data in the drive `Drive 2`. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Those are just two *partitions* on one drive.)

Converting a data disk (without an OS) to GPT is usually painless, as only the partition table (containing start & end locations) needs to be rewritten – the partitions themselves do not need to be touched at all.

On Linux the `gdisk` tool can be used for this.

1. Boot a Linux CD (e.g. [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) or [Arch](https://www.archlinux.org/download/)).
2. Open a **Terminal** window (if the CD has a graphical interface).
3. Run **`lsblk`** to check what disks & partitions are present.
   If you have only one, it's almost always "sda", but check anyway.
4. If the disk is "sda", run **`sudo gdisk /dev/sda`** to run the gdisk tool.
   It will warn you about a MBR partition table and will automatically convert it to GPT.
5. Use the `p` (Print) command to look at the results – if you want.
6. Use the **`w`** (Write) command to **save the changes**, or `q` (Quit) to cancel them.
7. Reboot.

(I think using the menu-based `cgdisk` would work just as well.)

Comment: /added a missing `sudo` as gdisk must be run as root

Comment: @qasdfdsaq: Nice that it finally has a non-destructive option for that, but would you mind posting your own _answer_ instead

Comment: @grawity in your solution will there be any data loss ?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is because the machine is booting to UEFI mode. You can still install Windows 8, you have a few options. Personally I would back up the data and reformat the drive. But there is third party software that can do that and retain your data as well. Following is your options:-

Reboot the PC in legacy BIOS-compatibility mode. This will allow you to build on it as is.

Format the drive GPT, if you want the data in drive 2 but don't want to do a backup (not recommended) use a third-party utility to convert the drive to GPT format.

Answer (score 0):

**Reformatting the drive using a different partition style**

To wipe and convert the drive by using Windows Setup

- Turn off the PC, and put in the Windows installation DVD or USB key.
- Boot the PC to the DVD or USB key in UEFI mode.
- From inside Windows Setup, press Shift+F10 to open a command prompt
  window, or goto advance settings and select command prompt.

Open the diskpart tool:

```
diskpart
```

Identify the drive to reformat:

```
list disk
```

Select the drive, and reformat it:

```
select disk <disk number>
clean
convert gpt
exit
```

- Close the command prompt window.
- Continue the Windows Setup installation.
- When choosing an installation type, select Custom. The drive will appear as a single area of unallocated space.
- Select the unallocated space and click Next. Windows begins the installation.

***This will destroy all data from your drive so to backup your data from drive 2 using command prompt to copy all the data to some external storage.***