# Error while installing Windows 10 on GPT partition - any solution to not to format whole disk?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, partitioning, windows-installation, gpt

I previously had Windows 10 and Ubuntu both installed on my system.
My Windows 10 got corrupted so I decided to reinstall windows on C Drive (`/dev/sda8`).
But it gave me an error so I decided to format C-Drive and then install Windows 10. Unfortunately, I am still unable to install Windows 10.

I am able to boot into Ubuntu and this is my Partitions in GParted :

[image: Partitions on Gpart]

I've deleted the old partitions created by windows so that I could install it fresh.

Now what I've tried is that I created a bootable Windows 10 USB using WoeUSB on Ubuntu and attempted to install Windows 10.

This is the error I got - 
" Windows detected that the EFI System Partition was formatted as NTFS. Format the EFI System partition as FAT32 and restart the installation. "

After searching on the internet I found that I've to delete all partitions and then convert the disk into MBR to install windows 10.

But I really don't want to delete partition `/dev/sda10` which is my D: Drive containing only data and `/dev/sda9` which has Ubuntu.

`/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sda7` both has the ubuntu bootloader

My system is UEFI based and Secure boot is off and I have no idea whether WoeUSB creates MBR or GPT bootable USB.

Is there any solution to install windows 10 without losing all partitions?

Edit: I tried this solution - [Link](https://superuser.com/questions/989617/windows-8-1-windows-cannot-be-installed-to-this-disk) by user @grawity

`sudo gdisk /dev/sda8` gave this as output :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to MBR is not a workaround and may cause more problems than it solves not to mention you don't get the benefits of GPT.

/dev/sda8 is a partition so opening gdisk on it attempts creating a partition table on that partition. You do not want to do this. When opening gdisk use /dev/sda

Based on the error message you got from Windows installer I can tell you it was in UEFI mode so your WoeUSB install is probably alright.

Windows is probably getting confused because you have two ESPs.

Comment: Deleting the extra Boot Esp flagged partition  worked for me.